# What disaster befell the earth in "The City of Ember"?

Tags: city-of-ember

Having only just watched the movie "City of Ember" and not having read the book, was there any mention of what disaster befell the Earth that forced the creation of the City of Ember? The city obviously was a massive undertaking and not something hastily thrown together.

Comment: I'd like to upvote twice for using *"befell"!*

Comment: Its unspecified in either the book or the film, the only mention is of an impending disaster and the nominal recovery period of 200 years.  The third book in the series indicates that it is indeed a global war that is the crisis that causes Ember to be built.

Comment: I would say that the giant bugs and animals that appeared in the movie point to a mutagen agent (radiation, poison) and the large time for the opening of the box would point to radiactive decay, so I would point to war (Won't answer as I have not read the book, either).

Comment: The nature of the technology in the base, and the earthquakes as the disaster was occuring suggests that it was not a single event (EVE meteor) but more likely a series of intermediate events that can shake the roots of mountains and burn the land.

The interesting point is that it only takes ~200 years to recover.  Maybe the primary weapons were more like Neutron bombs - where they blast and kill, but they do not poison all life (plutonium is toxic in parts per billion).

Comment: The book has 2 sequels and 1 prequel set 50 years before the Disaster.  I've only read Ember and Sparks, but the summary to the prequel, [The Prophet of Yonwood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prophet_of_Yonwood), indicates the answer might be near the end of that book (and the cover is rather telling as well).

Comment: I highly recommend you read the whole series of City of Ember. You will find your answer in there.

Answer (score 11):

**As revealed in the second book, there were a series of plagues & wars that ravaged mankind.**

---

### Speculation from "The City of Ember"

Neither the book nor the movie specify what disaster befell the world. The [original book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_of_Ember) only refers to "impending disaster", but we can make some educated guesses based on the evidence:

- It wasn't sudden. The Builders had several years' notice, which they used to plan & build the underground city.
- The world was expected to recover within 200 years. This rules out any kind of heavy radiation, which would take several centuries to decay.
- The city's residents would be safe underground, which may rule out earthquakes or any sort of heavy tectonic activity. Then again, we don't know where precisely the city is located at - it could conceivably be in one of the few locations that aren't susceptible to such activity.
- The air was not affected. The city did not have any kind of air filtration system (as far as we know), only a ventilation system. This indicates the air on the surface was still safe.

From this evidence, we can narrow it down to something that they saw coming ahead of time, would only affect the surface, and the effects of which would only last a couple of centuries. This rules out most natural disasters and any kind of nuclear war or doomsday device.

Possibilities include an asteroid collision, a new ice age, or a prolonged conflict (either featuring unknown technology or perhaps against aliens).

---

### Description from "The People of Sparks"

**UPDATE:** The second book - [The People of Sparks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People_of_Sparks) - reveals quite a bit more about what happened. In it, the people of Ember

> evacuate the underground city and find a village of people living on the surface. These people refer to it as simply "The Disaster" and have survived on the surface ever since with a technology level closer to the 18th century than that of Ember.

One of the boys describes the Disaster like so, although he may only be repeating what he was taught (which might not be totally accurate):

> He leaned forward, elbows on his knees, and in a low, husky voice told
>   Lina about the weapons they had had in those days, the guns that let
>   you kill people without even getting near them, and the bombs that
>   could flatten and burn whole cities at once. "They set the cities on
>   fire all over the world," Torren said. His small eyes glittered. "And
>   afterward came the plagues."
>
> "I don’t know what a plague is," Lina said.
>
> "A sickness," said Torren. "The kind where one person catches it from
>   another person, and it spreads around fast before you can stop it."
>
> "We had one of those," Lina said. "The coughing sickness. It would
>   come sometimes and kill a lot of people and then go away again."
>
> "We had three," said Torren, as if three plagues were better than one.
>   "There was the one where you wither away, like you’re starving to
>   death; the one where you  feel like you’re on fire and you die of
>   heat; and the one where you suddenly can’t breathe. No one knew where
>   they came from, they just rose up and swept over the whole world like
>   a wind."
>
> Lina shuddered. She was tired, all at once, of listening to Torren,
>   who took such pleasure in describing horrors and saying words she
>   didn’t understand.
>
> "So," Torren said. "The Four Wars and the Three Plagues—those together
>   were the Disaster. When it finally got over with, hardly any people
>   were left. That’s why we had to start all over again."

So, according to Torren, the world was devastated by four wars in succession, apparently fought using conventional weaponry. His description of the bombs *could* describe nuclear weaponry, but the 200-year timeframe would appear to refute that. Another possibility is ballistic solid-core missiles launched from satellites, which would be almost as powerful as nuclear bombs but without the pesky radioactive fallout (still a ginormous dust cloud, however).

Following the wars, the survivors were then ravaged by three different plagues of varying symptoms. As before, these plagues *could* possibly be descriptions of radiation poisoning, but 200 years is simply not enough time to account for decay of nuclear fission materials (despite what Fallout says). Something more like 50,000 years would be more realistic, and that would also explain why the plants & animals had changed so much. But the box was specifically set to 200 years in both book and movie. We know that the Founders were advanced enough to have crystal-based solar energy technology, as seen in [the final book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diamond_of_Darkhold). Fusion bombs could account for the short recovery period, but not for the sickness or mutated animals.

In the end, we're still left with the mystery of what actually happened, albeit a bit less of one.

Comment: Just saying: 200 years *is* "several centuries"...

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Most people would not consider 2 to be several. If you google "several definition", you get "more than two but not many".

Comment: Umm.  Hiroshima and Nagasaki were rebuilt after the war.  I think the residents would refute your argument that it would take hundreds of years for the cities to be liveable again.

Comment: @JRE - the bombs used on Hiroshima and Nagasaki were playthings compared to modern nuclear warheads. The rule for measuring decay is division, so the more radiation there is initially, the longer it will take for it to dissipate. Chernobyl, for example, was something like 200x the radiation of the Japan nukes, and as a result will not be fit for human habitation for several thousand years yet.

Answer (score 4):

All of you are sort of right. here is an excerpt from the end of "Prophet of Yonwood".

> All over the world, people who believed in one truth fought against people who believed in a different truth, all of them believing theirs was the only *real* truth, and all of them willing to do anything-absolutely anything-to defend it. Nations readied and aimed their missiles. They sent their soldiers to take over cities and fight for land, and as the fighting swarmed across deserts and jungles and seas, new diseases broke out, and warring troops and fleeing refugees carried them to one country after another; hundreds of thousands died. Fear ran like a pack of wolves across the planet, and people were afraid for the survival of the human race.

Answer (score 2):

According to the second book, there were four wars with bombs and three plagues. This happened because, according to the third book, the United States and a country called Phalanx Nations disagreed.

Comment: If it's possible, can you find exact quotes?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! If you believe your answer is right, try supporting it with some quotes from the book you reference. Take a look on the tour page to see the the kind of answers we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the biggest clue is where one of the builders asks the rhetorical question what have we done. Obviously it was a human triggered disaster. Something that caused an extinction event where another asked if 200 years was long enough. They also mentioned that the city would protect itself.

While there isn't enough to go on for any one answer to be definitive, I do think that something on the surface, man made, was killing people at an alarming rate. Possibly some form of climate control gone wrong, disease doesn't make sense because if they could control it enough to build ember disease free they could likely just stay on the surface. The mutations in animals would suggest the use of creative license on the author's part. No amount of radioactive material would make moles that big if that's what the author had in mind. It is a typical sci-fi take on radiation mutation but it is not possible.

My vote is either some form of radioactive apocalypse in which the author didn't know enough about to write in a factual way, which in a fictional book is not a big deal to me, or it was some sort of human environment control effect gone wrong. Something that might have inadvertently tweaked nature into growing huge monsters for animals.

Answer (score 0):

I've read all the books. What seems likely is that The Nations and US had a conflict clearly. What doesn't make sense is that you don't see any army vehicles. Which means it couldn't be a ground war. But instead, I think that use maybe a special weapon that doesn't currently that only took out humans. How it may work is that it was in the air which explains the plague. So The weapons used were biological weapons that affected the air in the world and would only affect humans. Also, we don't see an air cleaner but these builders had brains and would have added some sort of air cleaner.

Comment: This could explain the weird animal changes due to the air so This to me is the most likely

Answer (score -2):

It's mentioned in the second book once they escape the city. There were 4 great wars and 3 plagues that make up the disaster.

The 3 plagues were:
1. You wither away and starve.
2. You feel like you're on fire and die.
3. You stop breathing suddenly.

Also, the wars we're caused by over population and fighting for resources. The builders knew an apocalypse was going to fall so they has it planned out. Actually a very interesting story, I just wish the author went more into detail on the disaster.

Comment: We always appreciate people providing new details for old questions, but I think everything you'd provided has been covered in greater detail before, with quotes from the books.